# How to generate a QR Code for an APK installation?

Tags: android, apk, qr-code

i have an Android app that has not been uploaded to Play Store yet and i want to share an APK through a QR code that will redirect to install the APK
Any suggestions ? thanks !!

Comment: There are countless free online QR code generators.

Comment: havent seen one that can create a QR code for an apk file ... have you ?

Comment: I believe that best you can do is to open Play Store url of your app.
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play
Automatic installation without user interaction would be major security issue.

Comment: well it is only for sharing the app between friends.. and i want it to be a QR code ..

Answer (score 1):

A QR code just contains a link. So you need to put the APK up on a website, then create a QR code with the URL of the file.